# Why do I get an indent error in this code from LPTHW ex41

Tags: python, indentation

Hi I'm a beginner learning with Zed Shaw's LPTHW (3rd ed). When i try to run the code in exercise 41 i get an indent error in line 42. I don't use the Tab button which seems to usually be the problem with indent errors. It's the second time it happened that I can't figure out whats wrong with the indentation. I'm running it in Powershell

```
    import random 
from urllib import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learnpythonthehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
     "Make a class named %%% thart is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object): \n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
     "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object): \n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
     "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
     "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
     "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
    "***.*** = '***'":
     "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

#do they want to drill phrases first
PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
  PHRASE_FIRST = True

  #load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
  WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snippet, phrase):
   class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in   
                  random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
   other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippets.count("***"))
   results = []
   param_names = [] 

   for i in range(0, snippets.count("@@@")):
       param_count = random.randint(1,3)
       param_names.append(','.join(random.samples(WORDS, param_count)))

   for sentence in snippet, phrase:
       result = sentence[:]

     #fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result. replace("%%%", word, 1)

    #fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

    #fake parameters list 
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        result.append(result)

    return results


    #keep going till they hit CTRL-D
try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets: 
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
               question, answer = answer, question

            print question

            raw_input(">")
            print "ANSWER:%s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError
  print "\nBye"
```

Comment: In `convert` the 3rd for loop down, `for word in class_names:` seems to be indented 1 space too far.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote (or need to remove the ```\``` in `\"`) on the third-to-last line. Look at the syntax highlighting. You're also missing a space after `except` on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running it through python's IDLE? It usually tells you what line to reffer back to for the indent error. That might help.

Comment: sorry meant to include that in the question it was line 42

Answer (score 0):

In convert the 3rd for loop down, for word in class_names: seems to be indented 1 space too far.

Comment: the following for loops are also indented too far